# Stack Memory Adress Differences

Tags: c++, stack-memory

i am new in c++.

I do have 2 code snippets.

**FIRST**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int firstInteger = 1;
    std::cout << "First memory adress: " << &firstInteger << std::endl;
    int secondInteger = 2;
    std::cout << "Second memory adress: " << &secondInteger << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result is

```
First memory adress: 00000039A2F7F934
Second memory adress: 00000039A2F7F954
```

Second integer has a bigger hex value.

**SECOND**

```
#include <iostream>

void someFunction() {
    int secondInteger = 2;
    std::cout << "Second memory adress: " << &secondInteger << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int firstInteger = 1;
    std::cout << "First memory adress: " << &firstInteger << std::endl;
    someFunction();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Result is

```
First memory adress: 00000093953EF744
Second memory adress: 00000093953EF624
```

First one is bigger this time.

---

Can somebody explain what is the difference between them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee of any ordering or distance between addresses of different variables (or complete objects in general), except that the storage of the objects will not overlap while they are in their lifetime. The compiler is allowed to layout the stack however it considers reasonable and efficient. It is wrong to assume any ordering must be present.

For example on GCC 12.2 x64 without optimization flags enabled I get a smaller address for the second variable in both cases [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1EnGrq5ns), but your behavior with `-O2` optimizations enabled [here](https://godbolt.org/z/c6osovGE4).

Comment: so for example when use the same compiler and compile the same code for 1000  times is it any chance that the order can change or it only can happen when i change the compiler type?

Comment: @UPinar It is unlikely that the compiler is designed to make the decision differently each time you run it on the same code. That would just cause problems. But it would be conforming to the C++ standard for the compiler to do so. In practice the compiler may make the decision differently e.g. if you change the types of the variable or other small details in the code. It may also make the decision differently in e.g. a new version or when it is passed different flags.

Comment: @UPinar It would even be conforming for multiple _runs_ of the same compiled program to order the addresses differently.